Monitor progress of python from within c# using python.net
From within c#, I am executing python.net to build a RandomForestClassifier.  After I have loaded the data and put it in a format for the classifier, using python.net I execute:
    scope.Exec("clf = RandomForestClassifier(verbose=2)");

followed by:
    scope.Exec("clf.fit(X_train, y_train")

The above executes without problem.  However, while "fitting", the RandomForestClassifier outputs a status message as each new tree in the forest is constructed. i.e.
"building tree n of 100".
I would like my C# application to capture each status output as it is reported.  At the start of execution, I have redirected stdout to a stringIO buffer.
    scope.Exec("my_stdout = sys.stdout = StringIO()")

and after executing a python statement, I retrieve output with:
    (string str = scope.Eval("my_stdout.getvalue()").ToString();

When I "Exec" the above fit function and then read the stdout, I get all 100 status messages.  Is there a way that I can create a thread to capture each of the status messages in my C# application individually as they happen?
